# Using Pyvista 3D and 2D plots in PYQT5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyvista

I am trying to plot 3D and 2D plots using Pyvista, I have been able to make the 3D plot work no issues. Once I add the 2D plot I have the following errors:

- I have to add an interactor widget to gridLayout_8, when I do the original size changes and the widget makes it increase in size. I am unsure how to avoid this.
- The following error also comes up when I close the app:

```
2022-02-05 15:13:00.876 (  45.002s) [                ]vtkWin32OpenGLRenderWin:758    ERR| vtkWin32OpenGLRenderWindow (0000011AA6CC1B50): failed to get vali
d pixel format.
ERROR:root:failed to get valid pixel format.
2022-02-05 15:13:00.876 (  45.003s) [                ]vtkOpenGLRenderWindow.c:493    ERR| vtkWin32OpenGLRenderWindow (0000011AA6CC1B50): GLEW could not be
initialized: Missing GL version
ERROR:root:GLEW could not be initialized: Missing GL version
2022-02-05 15:13:00.876 (  45.003s) [                ]     vtkOpenGLState.cxx:1795  WARN| Hardware does not support the number of textures defined.
2022-02-05 15:13:00.876 (  45.003s) [                ]     vtkOpenGLState.cxx:1795  WARN| Hardware does not support the number of textures defined.
2022-02-05 15:13:00.876 (  45.003s) [                ]     vtkOpenGLState.cxx:1795  WARN| Hardware does not support the number of textures defined.
2022-02-05 15:13:00.876 (  45.003s) [                ]     vtkOpenGLState.cxx:1795  WARN| Hardware does not support the number of textures defined.
2022-02-05 15:13:00.876 (  45.003s) [                ]     vtkOpenGLState.cxx:1795  WARN| Hardware does not support the number of textures defined.
2022-02-05 15:13:00.877 (  45.003s) [                ]     vtkOpenGLState.cxx:1795  WARN| Hardware does not support the number of textures defined.
2022-02-05 15:13:00.877 (  45.003s) [                ]     vtkOpenGLState.cxx:1795  WARN| Hardware does not support the number of textures defined.
```

Sorry these scripts have too many lines to fit on here.

Main Code
https://pastebin.com/nMPWWeU5

pyvistaGUI
https://pastebin.com/h5wiLYCY

What it should look like
[image: What it should look like]

What it looks like now
[image: What it looks like now]

I would greatly appreciate anyone's help with this!